# Mapping a drive in elfinder inside files folder

Tags: php, jquery, elfinder

1. Here I am mapping D drive in elfinder
2. I am not able to open files.

Here's my code.

```
$opts = array(
        // 'debug' => true,
        'roots' => array(
            array(
                'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
                'path'          => 'D:/pdf/', // path to files (REQUIRED)
                'URL'           => 'D:/pdf/',  // URL to files (REQUIRED)
                'accessControl' => 'access'    // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally browser will open only url not path. We have to convert path into url.

If you want to map a drive (D drive) create a virtual directory in XAMMP.
Add below code in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   <Directory "D:/pdf">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
   ServerAdmin anbu@local.dev
   DocumentRoot "D:/pdf"
   ServerName local.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Now restart your server.

modify url in blow code

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => 'D:/pdf/', // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => 'http://local.dev',  // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access'    // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);
```

hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is incorrect. Please see the example in the [documentation](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options):

```
$opts = array(
    'locale' => '',
    'roots'  => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
            'path'   => '/path/to/files/',
            'URL'    => 'http://localhost/to/files/'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: But I would like map drive D instead localhost. is there any possibility ?

Comment: Of course. Keep `path` the same, you just need to change the `url` to what you want it to be when accessing the files over the web

Comment: I am developing intranet and this part for file sharing. when I open the file the url will be 'http://localhost/D:/pdf/ I am not able remove localhost from url. If I remove that manually it works fine.

Comment: I don't think you want localhost/D:/pdf as the URL? Surely something like `http://localhost/pdf`? or /d/pdf... You'd better have a read of the docs again if you're still having trouble.